# Wine "runtime error 91" in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wine

Has anyone tried to load the ballistics program "**Load from a disk**" into Ubuntu 12.04 with Wine? I have it installed but on startup (very first screen) I get the message:

> runtime error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set.

and the program doesn't load.

I am a total newbie with this OS. Previous MS user, so if anyone has a solution, try to make it as simple as possible. Regardless, I'll appreciate any and all help available.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried this winetrick :

```
winetricks jet40 mdac28
```

It is like a add-on that is used in wine to support I think some VB and Database connectivity Features

Comment: This needs a fuller explanation please. What is that and what does it do?

Comment: I'd like to have the same information.  I would prefer not to just throw commands into play blindly.

Comment: It is like a add-on that is used in wine to support I think some VB and Database connectivity Features

Comment: this solved my issues

Answer (score 0):

## `wine:i386` might not be installed

On a `amd64` system, this might be an indication of `wine:i386` not being installed.
First, check whether multi-arch support is configured:

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

This should yield `i386` on `amd64` systems. If not, configure it with:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Then, proceed with installing `wine32-preloader:i386` and `winetricks`:

```
$ sudo apt install wine32-preloader:i386 winetricks
```

Finally, it might be wise to install the [latest PlayOnLinux release](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html) for Ubuntu.